# Access Dashboard for live Excel file

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007

I'm creating a dashboard in Access that watches an excel spreadsheet we use for data entry. It's important that we avoid locking the spreadsheet out, so I've been using a saved data import that runs on a timer. The code works perfectly the first time it runs. On the second refresh the listbox returns blank and the table's data is deleted.

My guess is that the listbox is locking the table, so I tried a DAO.Recordset but I had the same issue.

How can I continue to get updates on this timer?

Private Sub Form_Timer()

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE test.* FROM TEST"
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "DWOR"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TEST", dbOpenDynaset)
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Set watcher.Recordset = rs
End If
'rs.Close
'Me.watcher.RowSource = db.OpenRecordset("Test")
'watcher.RowSource = "SELECT [test].[#], [test].[Line Set], [test].[Model], [test].[Chassis Def], [test].[Chassis Short], [test].[Cab-L], [test].[Cab-C MRU/LEU], [test].[Cab Short], [test].[Paint Qual], [test].[Paint Damage], [test].[Paint Short], [test].[MTR Rm], [test].[ENG], [test].[Westport], [test].[Vendor], [test].[Hood], [test].[Sleeper], [test].[Sub-Assem], [test].[OFFLINE] FROM test ORDER BY [#]; "
watcher.Requery
```

End Sub

EDIT:
I moved the event to a button and the listbox and table fields all appear as #Deleted.

Comment: Need more info... What is the timer interval set to? I assume no error messages produced?  What is 'Watcher'? Is that the form namewhere this code resides? If yes, why not set the form recordsource to "TEST" then requery that? If so you should close and release RS and DB when finished.  Also, IMO, where you test Recordcount > 0, if you move to ADO that will not work correctly (it returns -1). I would replace that line with "If not rs.eof then".  To help debug, on the second time thru, display recordcount of TEST. If > 0, then issue is in RecordSource / Requery.

Comment: The timer interval is set for 10 seconds. No error messages are thrown, it just clears out the table. Test is just the name of the table. Watcher is the name of the listbox.

I'll try binding the listbox straight to the 'TEST', I was just trying to avoid locking the table.

EDIT: Binding the listbox locks up the table I believe. No error message was tossed up, but the table was never updated (rather than update once and then clear out)

Comment: To help debug, can you add a display after the import to count the number of records in the table? If zero, then the issue is with the import.

Comment: Yeah, they're coming up as a zero. I used a saved import from the import wizard. Is there a manual way to set up an import that wouldn't cause this problem?

Comment: Yes, you can just use the command: i.e.
strFilePath = "C:\data\excel\2014OriolesSchedule.xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tblFromExcel", strFilePath, True

Answer (score 0):

Can you set up your Excel file as a linked table instead of bringing in the data to a permanent table? This will not cause locking in the Excel file. Then when you need to refresh you just run something like this

```
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Set tdf = db.TableDefs("your linked table name")

tdf.RefreshLink
```

The data on your form will be automatically updated when the underlying table is updated.

Comment: A linked table is exactly what I need, I've just been avoiding it because I've always run into problems with a linked table locking users out.

Is there perhaps something I'm missing that would cause a linked table to lock the excel file?

Comment: @Duffie How are you setting up your `Recordset Type`? I'm using `Snapshot` which does not seem to cause locking. I can have my form open in Access and whenever I make a change in Excel I hit refresh and the change moves through (I didn't even hit save).

Comment: If I try to open the linked table to view the records the connection gets all messed up (connection lost and values look like `#ERROR`) but so long as I look at it through the form everything works.